# Help to identify (narrow dark-green pointed leaf with white midrib)

Tags: identification

[image]I live in NC, I have something growing in front yard and not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1):

[Chimaphila maculata (spotted wintergreen aka striped wintergreen aka striped prince's pine aka spotted pipsissewa aka ratsbane aka rheumatism root)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimaphila_maculata)

Confirmed with a likelihood of 70% using identify.plantnet.org.

Actually, I think it is a little bit rare:

> **Conservation status**
>
> Spotted wintergreen is endangered in Canada, as there are four living populations in southern Ontario, and there is
> one extremely small extant population in Quebec.
>
> It is endangered in Illinois and Maine. In New York it is considered
> Exploitably Vulnerable.

### Edit:

User Jurp is right: This answer should be more accurate:
I mainly used information from [this](https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/chimaphila-maculata/) page for identification, especially picture 4, 14 and 16 from the left.

In US this genus contains three species. The two other ones can be ruled out because of the location (North Caroline, US), and the very clear white midrib stripe called "identifying characteristic".

Habitat:

> This plant needs very well-drained, preferably acidic sandy soils, in
> shady conditions.

I did a search with the Latin name and "confusion", and I only think I found other members of this genus.

Personally, I would not disturb the roots, but they are [rhizomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizome). Elsewhere the best to do is to wait for flowers, which should appear in the "summer".

Comment: Pipsissewa is indeed uncommon. I've been lucky enough to see it, and I'm not positive that this is what the OP's plant is. Not positive that it isn't, either. Two good keys are: Is it growing in sun or in a shaded woodland? (If in sun, then the plant is NOT pipsissewa) unless the area was freshly cleared. Are the flowers (which should be blooming just about now if the plant is 2 years old or older) the same as in the Wikipedia page? In any case, I would NOT kill this plant - even if it's not pipsissewa it is still a striking plant and almost certainly NOT a pernicious weed.